# docplex - get relaxation objective value

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I am trying to get the objective value of the relaxation of a MIP model with cocplex. Is there a way to find this value without relaxing the model and solving it an extra time ?

This [library](https://ibmdecisionoptimization.github.io/docplex-doc/mp/docplex.mp.relaxer.html) might to the job but I can't manage to make it work.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To make things run more smoothly, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) of how SO works and especially [How To Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then please edit your question with more detail so others could help you out.